# fire edit/delete actions on custom column ng2-smart-table

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I have added a column with custom renderer like this,

```
settings = {
   actions: false,
   columns: {
      operation:{
         title:"operation",
         type: 'custom',
         renderComponent: CustomActionRenderComponent,
      }
}
```

and now it looks like this :
[image]

I want to fire the default edit or delete action when user clicks on link in dropdown.
Basically I want to call the same function which are invoked when default action column is enabled and links in that column are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried calling default functions of ng2-smart table, but could not achieve in doing so.

So i used **OnComponentInitFunction()** for emitting actions from **renderComponent**.

Below is the sample code:

```
 {
title: "Actions",
type: "custom",
  renderComponent: ActionRenderComponent,
    onComponentInitFunction:(instance) => {
      instance.actionEmitter.subscribe(row => {
        if (row == 'Edit') {
          //invoke your methods here
        }
        if (row == 'delete') {
          //invoke your methods here      
        });
    },
      filter: false
  }
};
```

As you can see above **actionEmitter** is the emitter from **renderComponent**